# Recovering from a bootloop in Lenovo S960

Tags: boot-loop, lenovo

I've recently rooted my phone and have installed Xposed Framework. I'm used to this process and know what the consequences are. The phone was working fine until I installed a module for Xposed called Tinted Statusbar. Activated it and rebooted. thats when the bootloop happened. Tried all methods for disabling Xposed. The xposed-disabler zip didn't work when i tried flashing it, the hardware buttons just vibrate.

How can i recover my phone? The recovery is an old CWM v2.2.2 running on a Mediatek Processor.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to overcome bootloop is to reflash the phone (start off on a clean slate) by using an SPFlashTool format firmware (where you have to use [SP Flash Tool](http://androidxda.com/smart-phone-flash-tool) to flash).

Irregardless of the version release, replace the original **recovery.img** file with either CWM/TWRP recovery  file and rename it to "recovery.img" file. This will ensure that immediately after the reflash you will have custom recovery installed already.(but in the original firmware folder there will be a "Checksum" file. Remove/expunge this file from the folder since the CWM/TWRP (if it has checksum that doesn't match with the original factory recovery checksum)).

Then search for a "custom Firmware for S960" from [NeedROM](http://www.needrom.com/) website and upgrade via TWRP/CWM. Install the latest updates you can find there (I do contribute firmwares on that site) and this bootloop issue is a normal occurence amongst users. I provide them with a downgraded firmware which is **SP Flash Tool** and then upgrade it back to the latest version with no issues, except you loose all the installes apps (better than having a paper weight!)

Answer (score 0):

Factory reset will work, but will wipe everything in the process. You will have to reinstall everything again.

This will work even if you installed all the modules to system. It resets the module list in the framework app, the modules have to be re-enabled.

Update the recovery to the newest version that your ROM will work with.

Please read this part carefully:

- ***`Always make a backup/nandroid BEFORE you add or change anything.`***

  ---
- Here is the [download page for Lenovo S960](http://www.android.gs/download-lenovo-stock-rom/) stock ROMs, plus install instructions. Latest ROM is 4.4.2 as of now.
- Here is the instructions and download page for [TWRP 2.6.3.0 and root](http://www.androidrookies.com/2014/04/how-to-install-twrp-2630-and-root-on.html?m=1). There are other recoveries, but TWRP seems the most stable for Lenovo.

Comment: tried Wiping data/factory reset in CWM, still bootloops. It reboots a few times then blank screen. @HasH_BrowN

Comment: Don't forget to wipe cache and dalvik-cache too!

Comment: Still same. Stock rom couldn't be found anywhere.

Comment: Same problem plus overheating..

Comment: @heywhite  edited my answer with ROM link

Comment: so should i install from ADB on my pc or should i push the file into my phone through ADB?

Comment: From either will be fine, but I (personal preference) would do it from the PC.

Comment: installation failed. Tried removing assert cuz the rom before was made by ROW

Comment: Well I guess that would leave you to do a complete wipe of the system, start it all from scratch. Nothing will get in the way then. You went this far